# Roundcoube exchange

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exchange, roundcube

Kак можно реализовать фильтры в связке Roundcoube exchange?

---

Стандартный filter сообщает 
PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /www/roundcube/plugins/filters/filters.php on line 247